# Rails 3 No Route Matches Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

My application uses tickets and call_logs. I have these nested in each other, so that tickets can have many call_logs.
I am getting the error with  [GET] "/call_logs"
I don't know what I am missing here. 
I do have my routes nested in **routes.rb**

```
  resources :tickets do
    resources :call_logs
  end
```

**rake routes**:

```
ticket_call_logs     GET    /tickets/:ticket_id/call_logs(.:format)          call_logs#index
                     POST   /tickets/:ticket_id/call_logs(.:format)          call_logs#create
 new_ticket_call_log GET    /tickets/:ticket_id/call_logs/new(.:format)      call_logs#new
edit_ticket_call_log GET    /tickets/:ticket_id/call_logs/:id/edit(.:format) call_logs#edit
     ticket_call_log GET    /tickets/:ticket_id/call_logs/:id(.:format)      call_logs#show
                     PUT    /tickets/:ticket_id/call_logs/:id(.:format)      call_logs#update
                     DELETE /tickets/:ticket_id/call_logs/:id(.:format)      call_logs#destroy
             tickets GET    /tickets(.:format)                               tickets#index
                     POST   /tickets(.:format)                               tickets#create
          new_ticket GET    /tickets/new(.:format)                           tickets#new
         edit_ticket GET    /tickets/:id/edit(.:format)                      tickets#edit
              ticket GET    /tickets/:id(.:format)                           tickets#show
                     PUT    /tickets/:id(.:format)                           tickets#update
                     DELETE /tickets/:id(.:format)                           tickets#destroy
```

**call_logs controller**:

```
class CallLogsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_ticket

  # GET /call_logs
  # GET /call_logs.json
  def index
    @call_logs = @ticket.call_logs.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @call_logs }
    end


    # GET /call_logs/1
    # GET /call_logs/1.json
    def show
      @call_log = @ticket.call_logs.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @call_log }
      end
    end

    # GET /call_logs/new
    # GET /call_logs/new.json
    def new
      @call_log = @ticket.call_logs.build

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @call_log }
      end
    end

    # GET /call_logs/1/edit
    def edit
      @call_log = @ticket.call_logs.find(params[:id])
    end

    # POST /call_logs
    # POST /call_logs.json
    def create
      @call_log = CallLog.new(params[:call_log])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @call_log.save
          format.html { redirect_to ticket_call_logs_url(@ticket), notice: 'Call log was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @call_log, status: :created, location: @call_log }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @call_log.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PUT /call_logs/1
    # PUT /call_logs/1.json
    def update
      @call_log = @ticket.call_logs.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @call_log.update_attributes(params[:call_log])
          format.html { redirect_to ticket_call_logs_url(@ticket), notice: 'Call log was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: "edit" }
          format.json { render json: @call_log.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /call_logs/1
    # DELETE /call_logs/1.json
    def destroy
      @call_log = @ticket.call_log.find(params[:id])
      @call_log.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to ticket_call_logs_path(@call_log)}
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end
end

    private
    def get_ticket
      @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
    end
```

I believe I have an error in my url paths when directing to the call_log page, but I can't seem to find it. Any advice or tips would be appreciated, as I am a noob. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the output of `rake routes`, You don't have a route that matches /call_logs. Since this is a nested resource route you have to prepend the tickets and ticket id: `/tickets/<id>/call_logs`.

Comment: Are you replacing <id> with a valid ticket id?

Comment: Yes, now I am getting the error: a undefined method `call_logs' for #<Ticket:0x3f1d478>.

Comment: This is not related to your routing. It probably has to do with not defining relations between the models.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have done changes in routes.rb but not maintaining relation in Models. As rake routes say 
ticket_call_logs     GET    /tickets/:ticket_id/call_logs(.:format)

Should be accessible by /ticket/id/call_logs , Now here "id" is ticket id. This will list all call logs for that particular ticket_id.